# docker compose build: failed to solve: changes out of order

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose

dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ./target/diplomAPI-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: mobilka
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 12345
```

error code:

```
PS C:\Users\extre\IdeaProjects\diplomAPI> docker-compose build
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)  docker:default
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)  docker:defaultr reading preface from client //./pipe/docker_engine: file has already been closed
[+] Building 2.2s (6/7)                                                                                                                                                                                              docker:default
 => [app internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 180B                                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s 
 => [app internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/openjdk:alpine                                                                                                                                                          2.0s 
 => [app auth] library/openjdk:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [app internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                0.0s 
 => ERROR [app internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 57B                                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s 
 => [app 1/2] FROM docker.io/library/openjdk:alpine@sha256:1fd5a77d82536c88486e526da26ae79b6cd8a14006eb3da3a25eb8d2d682ccd6                                                                                                    0.0s 
------
 > [app internal] load build context:
------
failed to solve: changes out of order: "target/diplomAPI-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" ""
```

The `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` files are in the same folder. The file `diplomAPI-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` actually exists and is located in the specified folder.

I attempted deleting a line `ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar` without any improvement.

I attempted to put the Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml in a separate folders and specified this path as the context without any improvement.

Comment: Please, edit your post and add the `docker build` command line.

Comment: Try to explicity specify the build context and ensure that it points to the correct directory where dockerFile and jar are located : build:
  context: /path/to/your/dockerfile
  dockerfile: Dockerfile and docker-compose build --no-cache

Answer (score 5):

The `failed to solve: changes out of order` error message is a bug in docker compose running in Docker Desktop.

[According to the issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/11421), this is resolved by upgrading our downgrading Docker Desktop to a version other than 4.27.1. You could also build with `docker build` directly, or attempt to disable buildkit with `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker compose build`.

Comment: Upvoted for the correct direction (link to the issue). (2) Disabling buildkit somehow didn't work for me: "'DOCKER_BUILDKIT' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." on Windows OS: c:\git\repo>DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose-mysql.yml up -d

Comment: @hitesh the command assumed using a bash shell.