# Docker compose error : changes out of order

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm having this error : failed to solve: changes out of order: "seed/fontstylegroups.json" "import-script.sh"

The *.json files are standard data for mongodd.

The Dockerfile

```
FROM mongo

COPY seed/*.json /seed/
COPY import-script.sh /import-script.sh

RUN chmod +x /import-script.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/import-script.sh"]
```

and the import script

```
#!/bin/bash
# Import script for MongoDB

# Use environment variables or default values
username="${MONGO_USERNAME:-admin}"
password="${MONGO_PASSWORD:-admin_123}"
host="${MONGO_HOST:-morefont-mongo}"
db="${MONGO_DB:-morefont}"

# Exit smoothly on any error
set +e

# Import each JSON file into its collection
for file in /seed/*.json; do
    collection=$(basename "$file" .json)
    mongoimport --username ${username} --password ${password} --authenticationDatabase "admin" --mode upsert --host ${host} --db ${db} --collection ${collection} --type json --file "$file" --jsonArray
done

# Exit with a status code of 0
exit 0
```

and the docker-compose file

```
version: "3.8" 
services:
  mongodb: # name of the third service
    image: mongo # specify image to build container from
    container_name: morefont-mongo
    volumes:
      - mongodb:/data/db
      - mongodb_config:/data/configdb
    ports:
      - "27017:27017" #specify ports ONLY DEV
    restart: always
    command: --quiet
    healthcheck:
      test: echo 'db.runCommand("ping").ok' | mongo localhost:27017/test --quiet
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    networks: 
      - npm-network 
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME}
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
  mongo-express:
   image: mongo-express
   container_name: morefont-mongo-express
   environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER: mongodb
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME}
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
   ports:
     - 8081:8081
   depends_on:
     - mongodb
   networks: 
     - npm-network

  mongo-seed:
      build: mongo
      environment:
        username: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME}
        password: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      networks: 
        - npm-network 
      restart: "no" 
networks:
  npm-network:
    name: npm_default
volumes:
   mongodb:
   mongodb_config:
```

The error appears only when using the docker-compose, it works fine if I run the dockerfile individually.

Comment: [docker compose build: failed to solve: changes out of order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77993212/docker-compose-build-failed-to-solve-changes-out-of-order)

Comment: Error due to Docker Desktop version 4.27.1 -> updating to 4.27.2 solved the issue